# User can't scroll down to all rows in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a simple form contain a `textbox`, `gridview` and a save button.
The user enter a customer name in the text box and press enter then i fetch data from database table then show them in the `gridview` and everything is good, but the problem accrued when the rows count is big and the scroll bar of the grid view appears so the user can scroll down to add new row or to browse couple last rows, but the surprise that i cant scroll down to all rows because the scroll bar only allow me to scroll to before the last couple or tree rows, so i have to select a row and then go down with down arrow on keyboard and it's so annoying and not professional.

Information might help that there is no spacial code that i use here to add rows to the grid just the normal way like this :

```
joinsGridView.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; ++i)
        {
            RegisterJointFormData item = dataList[i];

            joinsGridView.Rows.Add();
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell joinNameCombo = joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["JoinName"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            joinNameCombo.Value = dataList[i].Join.JoinTypeID;
            joinTypeBindingSource.Position = joinTypeBindingSource.IndexOf(item.Join.JoinType);
            joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["JoinPrice"].Value = item.Join.JoinType.Price;
            joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Discount"].Value = item.Join.Discount;
            joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["PayedMoney"].Value = item.PayedMoney;
            joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["RegisterDate"].Value = item.Join.RegisterDate.ToShortDateString();
            joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Duration"].Value = item.Join.JoinType.Duration;
            joinsGridView.Rows[i].Cells["SessionsAttened"].Value = item.SessionsAttend;
        }
```

Another info that i am using Entity Framework to connect to database and get data.

I hope i described the problem right and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Now i have customers using my product and i want to fix it to shut them up, and i have been using winforms for years and this the first time something like this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last i found the problem and it's very silly as i expected, the problem was that i am disabling the grid at form load and after the user enter customer name i fill the grid with data then enable it and it's fixed by enabling the grid first then add the data to the grid.